# Distribute a certificate within an organisation

Tags: group-policy, certificate

I want to distribute a certificate (.cer file) to users within an OU. It is used to encrypt .pdf files so that only company machines with said certificate installed can view the file. I created the certificate using Adobe Acrobat 9 Standard and did some testing on my computer and everything seemed fine.

Now I want to have this certificate installed on other machines, my first approach was to create a GPO and run `certutil` through a .bat file. After running it successfully on a test OU, I tried linking the same GPO to a live OU but it did not work (I've read up on GPO troubleshooting and tried fixes such as loopback but had no success).

Then I tried using a certificate import wizard under Trusted Root Certification Authorities on the same GPO as explained [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770315%28WS.10%29). It has yet to show up on client machines.

So my question is, what can I do to fix my earlier attempts or is there another method that is sure to distribute my certificate to others?

Comment: is the cer-file in a location the clients can access? By the way: as far as i know, there are specific GPOs for certificat deployment: https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/Cc947849(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: As part of my troubleshooting for the first approach I made a hidden folder on the server and shared it with users and had certutil directly import the certificate from that directory. Not only this did not work, but it can have potential issues (users finding about the folder and accessing the .bat file which contains the password). Furthermore in my experience this method isn't 100% reliable.

Comment: Somehow the clients must acces the certificate, so it has to be in a folder, where the clients have access. But i don't understand what password is needed for the deployment of a certificate?

Comment: Honestly I'm not to sure why there's a password included because I created it a while back and only revisiting this side project now. But I will try that link you provided and hopefully it will fix things.